# How do I pass initial state to my reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following react-redux store:

```
let store;

const initStore = ({onRehydrationComplete}) => {

  store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      ...reactDeviseReducers,
      form: formReducer,
      router: routerReducer,
      apollo: apolloClient.reducer(),
      cats
    }),
    {},
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunk,
        routerMiddleware(history),
        apolloClient.middleware()
      ),
      autoRehydrate(),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
  );

  persistStore(store, {
    blacklist: [
      'form'
    ]
  }, onRehydrationComplete);

  return store;
};
```

How can I pass initial state to the reducers and to my app?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, is that the way to do it? inital state per reducer and not per the main store?

Comment: Well, the whole point of splitting up your reducers is to "slice up" state and provide each reducer with a part of state the certain reducer manages itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your initial state as the second argument of [`createStore`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html):

> `createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])`
>
> 2. [`preloadedState`] *(any)*: The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced `reducer` with `combineReducers`, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.

I would personally suggest setting initial state per each reducer, specific to that reducer. For example, in a Todo App:

```
const initialState = [
    { text: "This is a todo!", completed: false }
];

function todos(state = initialState, action) {
    ...
}
```

Here, the `todos` reducer only knows about it's certain "slice" of state, not the whole application state. It only knows about an array of todos, not everything else in state. Though, in this case, this might not be possible